Qcow2 file created by backup is smaller and not sparse
The backups created by the virsh backup-begin command are not sparse, and only big enough to hold the amount of data being stored.
I used the process described here to create a backup of a virtual machine's qcow2 file.
https://libvirt.org/kbase/live_full_disk_backup.html
The original file showed an apparent size of 300 GB, with 60 GB allocated.
The backup file shows an apparent size of 60 GB, all of which is presumably allocated.
The backup file seems to work OK as the disk on a newly created VM, and when disk space is used by the guest the size of this file is increased.
Question: is there a loss of performance in having to increase the size of the disk file every time more space is needed?  If so, what do I do to the file to avoid this?
thanks,
Steve
